# Erro php, Call to undefined function http_get()

Tags: php, linux

Procurei formas de resolver esse problema para usar a função `http_get()`, todos mandavam instalar a lib php-http e pelo *pecl* o *http.so*

Fiz isso e setei no `apache2/php.ini` as bibliotecas dessa forma:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/http.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/raphf.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/propro.so
```

Dei o comando `service apache2 restart` e o problema ainda continua, alguem sabe se falta mais alguma coisa? Lembrando que é no Linux Mint/Ubuntu.

Comment: Olha aqui: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html e aqui: http://php.net/manual/en/http.install.php

Comment: Essa é a versão anterior do: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get.php faça: apt-get install php-http

Comment: Já tinha feito tudo isso... até reiniciei o computador! Mas nada deu certo até agora, tenho a impressão que não pega as alterações no php.ini, sei la.

Comment: Resolvi desinstalar e instalar novamente o pecl_http e quando uso o comando **var_dump(extension_loaded("http"));** ele imprime TRUE, mas o comando http_get continua sem funcionar e dando o erro **Fatal error: Call to undefined function http_get() in /home/andre/www/get_php.php on line 5**

Comment: Acho que não precisa fazer nada manualmente, só instalação já coloca as "extensions" corretamente. Olha aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/http.install.php, remova isso que vc fez e digite no terminal o comando: `apt-get install php5-dev && apt-get install libcurl3 && apt-get install libmagic && apt-get install php-http && pecl install pecl_http`

Comment: Isso eu fiz no inicio de tudo! Não deu certo.

Comment: Talvez seu código não esteja utilizando o método `http_get()` adequadamente.

Comment: Boa noite, testou a minha resposta?

Comment: Hummm... isso já faz um tempo que aconteceu! Não lembro direito, mas acho que resolvi esse problema usando curl! Mas agradeço a todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não consegui resolver o problema com http_get (não tinha conseguido configurar), por isso acabei trabalhando com curl.

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Conforme esta resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26353856/1518921) e o [link](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http#Dependencies:) você tem que incluir **na ordem correta**, esta é a ordem:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/raphf.so
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/propro.so

;Este só deve vir depois
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/http.so
```

Se configurado o `--with-http-shared-deps` (padrão) talvez dependa das seguintes extensões e nesta ordem:

```
extension = raphf.so
extension = propro.so

extension = hash.so
extension = iconv.so
extension = json.so

;Este só deve vir depois
extension = http.so
```

Um exemplo de uso:

```
<?php
$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/", array("timeout"=>1), $info);
print_r($info);
```

> Note que a documentação não tem mais dados sobre esta extensão (que é PECL), apesar de ainda ter um link perdido http://php.net/manual/it/ref.http.php - Agora só disponível nos links https://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http e [documentação](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http#Dependencies:)